# How to Request for Alternative Routes In here maps SDK (Android)?

Tags: android, navigation, here-api

Before starting the navigation I wanted to show Alternative routes for the user and I will watch selection from "onMapObjectsSelected". I saw this "new RouteOptions().setRouteCount(mutltipleroutecount)" instead of this do we have any other method.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5nnen.png)

Comment: Why are you searching for an alternative to the setRouteCount method ? What's wrong with it ? It's the right way to do it. Set the amount of alternative routes, get route results array with several routes if available, put them all on the map and react on the mapobject select events.... If it's not working, would be helpful to see some code.

Comment: As Marco has requested, please show some code so we can help

Answer (score 0):

As HERE Support has already requested, we need to see the example code or your code to suggest our help.